# Raster: Extract center of raster images (geoTIFF) and draw its borders

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I've like to extract coordinates (and create a data frame) of the center of 4 raster sub-images in geoTIFF and draw the border of 2 selected sub-images, originally split in the `r2` image, for this I try:

```
library(raster)  
library(rgeos)

#create GeoTIFF raster
r <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
s <- stack(lapply(1:3, function(i) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))
f1 <- file.path(tempdir(), "sl1.tif")
writeRaster(s,f1, format="GTiff",datatype="FLT4S",overwrite=TRUE)

#crop in 4 sub-images
r2<-stack(raster("sl1.tif"))
SplitRas <- function(raster,ppside,save,plot){
  h        <- ceiling(ncol(raster)/ppside)
  v        <- ceiling(nrow(raster)/ppside)
  agg      <- aggregate(raster,fact=c(h,v))
  agg[]    <- 1:ncell(agg)
  agg_poly <- rasterToPolygons(agg)
  names(agg_poly) <- "polis"
  r_list <- list()
  for(i in 1:ncell(agg)){
    e1          <- extent(agg_poly[agg_poly$polis==i,])
    r_list[[i]] <- crop(raster,e1)
  }
  if(save==T){
    for(i in 1:length(r_list)){
      f1 <- file.path(tempdir(), paste0("sample_",i,sep=""))
      writeRaster(r_list[[i]], f1,
                  format="GTiff",datatype="FLT4S",overwrite=TRUE)
    }
  }
  if(plot==T){
    par(mfrow=c(ppside,ppside))
    for(i in 1:length(r_list)){
      plot(r_list[[i]],axes=F,legend=F,bty="n",box=FALSE)
    }
  }
  return(r_list)
}
splitRBG<-SplitRas(raster=r2,ppside=2,save=TRUE,plot=FALSE)
# 

#read the 4 images 
r.files <-list.files(tempdir(), pattern = "sample")
#[1] "sample_1.tif" "sample_2.tif" "sample_3.tif" "sample_4.tif"

# get coordinates data from the center of each image
RES<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(r.files)){
value <- raster::extract(?????????) ## Here Im loosing for extract the center of each image
RES<-rbind(RES,cbind(r.files[i],coordinates(value))) #create a data frame of the results
}
colnames(RES)<-c("r.files","xcoord","ycoord")
```

First for I've like to create a data frame with this information

```
r.files         xcoord       ycooord      
sample_1.tif     -100         -50
sample_2.tif      50          -52
sample_3.tif      120          50
sample_4.tif      120         -30
```

Here my first problem, because I don't find I way to extract the center of each image before I expected:

```
#Finally draw a square with the images and points in center of coordinates only for sample_3 and sample_4
del<-c("sample_1.tif","sample_2.tif")
r.files2<-r.files [-del]
RES2<-RES[,-(1:2)]
image(r2)
for(i in 1:length(r.files2)){
e <- extent(r.files2[i])
pp <- rasterToPolygons(e, dissolve=TRUE) 
plot(pp, border='green') #Only countour color
points(RES2[i][,2], RES2[i][,3],col="red")
}
```

Any ideas ou more smart solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the centre of a raster, take the mean of the min and max in each direction from the extent. Sample raster:

```
> r = raster(extent(23,29,3,12))
```

Get extent as a vector of xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax:

```
> e = as.vector(extent(r))
```

Compute mean of first two elements as X coordinate centre, last two elements as Y coordinate centre:

```
> c(mean(e[c(1,2)]),mean(e[c(3,4)]))
[1] 26.0  7.5
```

If you also want the coordinates of the corners of the raster then you can also get that from the extent vector by combining (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymin) etc in the four ways needed to get the four corners:

```
> cbind(e[c(1,1,2,2)],e[c(3,4,3,4)])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   23    3
[2,]   23   12
[3,]   29    3
[4,]   29   12
```

Note I was a bit put off from this question by all the code at the start, which seems unnecessary to the answer, unless I've missed a subtlety somewhere... Try and make the simplest example necessary to illustrate your question.